# Typescript typings for Cypress Request Response body object?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, cypress

I'm new to TypeScript, and I'm reworking my Cypress API-only test suite to use TypeScript. My goal is to spec out the endpoints in a way so TypeScript knows that `response.body.email` is a string in my code, etc., so that I don't have to rely on implicit 'any' type:

```js
cy.request('GET', '/foo')
    .then((response) => {
       // TS knows `response.body.email` is a string and `response.body.count` is a number
```

In a perfect world, it could pick this up directly from Swagger definitions, but I'm okay with more manual methods.

**Is it possible to achieve this?**

Ideally, I'd be able to integrate with one of these two NPM modules: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cypress/schema-tools or https://www.npmjs.com/package/@jc21/cypress-swagger-validation

It looks like in my `node_modules/cypress/types/index.d.ts`, they have the following relevant bits:

```
declare namespace Cypress {
    interface Response {
        allRequestResponses: any[]
        body: any
        duration: number
        headers: { [key: string]: string }
        isOkStatusCode: boolean
        redirectedToUrl: string
        requestHeaders: { [key: string]: string }
        status: number
        statusText: string
    }

    interface Chainable<Subject = any> {
        request(url: string, body?: RequestBody): Chainable<Response>
        request(method: HttpMethod, url: string, body?: RequestBody): Chainable<Response>
        request(options: Partial<RequestOptions>): Chainable<Response>
    }
}
```

Comment: I've come up with an ugly but workable solution, namely creating a boatload of interfaces, then making wrapper methods for cy.request, with return type `Cypress.Chainable<MyCustomResponseType<Bar>>`. Would greatly appreciate a better solution, though!

Comment: (You can see a modified form of my ugly but workable solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60184009/possible-to-chain-generics-in-cypress-custom-command-chains )